# How make a regex to check if a string is a float number with 7 digits and any value decimal place?

Tags: python, regex

How make a regex to check if a string is a float number with 7 digits and any value decimal place?

Being acceptable as decimal separator ; : - , . ?

So I need:

```
import re

    rgx = re.compile('What is the regex sintaxe for it ?')

tests=[7000000.00 7000000:00 7000000,00 7000000-00 7AAAAAA.00 700000000.00 70.00]

for s in tests:
    m = rgx.search(s)
    print(bool(m), s)

True 7000000.00
True 7000000:00
True 7000000,00
True 7000000-00
False 7AAAAAA.00
False 700000000.00
False 70.00
```

]

Example of how use regex

```
import re
    
    rgx = re.compile(r'\d+(?:,\d*)?')
    
    tests=['7000000.00', '7000000:00', '7000000,00', '7000000-00', '7AAAAAA.00', '700000000.00', '70.00']
    
    for s in tests:
        m = rgx.search(s)
        print(bool(m), s)
```

Comment: Can you show a reproducible example of your code? What you've shown in the question is syntactically incorrect

Comment: I just need the regex sintaxe; But ok i  will post some example for you.

Comment: This site is great for working out regex patterns https://www.pythex.org

Answer (score 2):

Check for `7 digits`, followed by one `non whitespace, non digit and non alphanumeric character` and ends with unlimited `numbers`:

```
import re

rgx = re.compile(r'[0-9]{7}[\S\D\W]{1}[0-9]+$')
# [0-9]{7}      >> Seven digits
# [\S\D\W]{1}   >> One non whitespace, non digit and non alphanumeric character
# [0-9].$       >> Ends with unlimited numbers

tests = "7000000.00 7000000:00 7000000,00 7000000-00 7AAAAAA.00 700000000.00 70.00"

for t in tests.split(" "):
    print(True if rgx.match(t) else False, t)
```

Out:

```
(True, '7000000.00')
(True, '7000000:00')
(True, '7000000,00')
(True, '7000000-00')
(False, '7AAAAAA.00')
(False, '700000000.00')
(False, '70.00')
```

Comment: Thx ,Could you explain how the regex sintaxe work for this case, pls?

Comment: @Kinille: Produces the same output as yours and what op expects.

Comment: @MauriceMeyer I'm testing them back and forth, and they have different outputs on the sixth case? Edit, I'm looking into how my testing is wrong

Comment: @Kinille: I get 4 Trues and 3 Falses in Python 2.7 and 3.9

Comment: I was splitting the tests beforehand and using the given code of the rgx.search() which behaves differently than rgx.match() which was causing my discrepancy. My bad

Comment: Your pattern is wrong because of `[\S\D\W]{1}`. `\S` contains the digits. So `12345678910111213` will match your pattern. Also, `\W` is included inside `\D` (since `\d` is included inside `\w`). In short `[\S\D\W]{1}` is exactly like `.` (with the `re.dotall` flag since it also matches newlines). I think a character class with only allowed decimal separator (and without quantifier) is more simple and works.

Answer (score 2):

After you specify a character class, you can specify how many of that character is needed using curly braces i.e. {1,2} meaning between 1 and 2 characters or {4} meaning 4 characters

```
re.compile(r'(^|\D)\d{7}[-.;:,]\d+')
```

Here's a rundown of the regex:

`(^|\D)` Means that either the character must not be a number, or must be the start of a line
`\d{7}` Seven digits in a row
`[-.;:,]` Any of your characters denoting a decimal point
`\d+` One or more digits

Of course you can add ^ and $ to ensure that the number is the only thing in the string if that's useful.

Comment: Not too quickly! Each shorthand character class `\d`, `\w`, `\s` ... has its [complement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complement_(set_theory)) (in a set theory meaning), `\D`, `\W`, `\S` ...